Rust equivalent of C++'s hardware_destructive_interference_size to help avoid false sharing
In order to avoid false sharing of cache lines, C++ added constants that provides a portable way to access the L1 data cache line size.
As per the C++ doc
hardware_destructive_interference_size would be minimum offset between two objects to avoid false sharing
Is there anything in Rust library that can provide something similar?

https://crates.io/crates/cache-size

This looks better if you don't need the raw number: https://docs.rs/crossbeam-utils/latest/crossbeam_utils/struct.CachePadded.html
